# discord bot command runs, but gets stuck trying to multiply

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

everything works fine, it prints the multiplication but it gets stuck on adding more coins to the server, it worked ok until I added the multiplier

```
import discord 
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 's!')
servermultiplier = 1
servercoins = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global servercoins, servermultiplier
    file1 = open("C:/Users/squid/Documents/Stuff/ok/save.txt", 'r')
    count = 0
    result = []
    for line in file1:
        count += 1
        result.append( line.strip())
    servercoins = result[0]
    serermultiplier = result[1]
    print(servercoins)
    print('Bot is ready!')
    channel = client.get_channel(id=864049237679538189)

@client.command(aliases=['8ball', '8b', 'eb'])
async def eightball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['no', 'kinda', 'i guess?', 'yes', '100%', 'absolutely not', 'what are you dumb?', 'sure', 'totaly']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnwser: {random.choice(responses)}')

@client.command(aliases=['b','money','cash','bal'])
async def balance(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Server has: **${servercoins}**')

@client.command(aliases=['give'])
async def givemoney(ctx):
    global servercoins, servermultiplier
    print('give', 1 * servermultiplier) #<- prints fine
    servercoins += 1 * servermultiplier #<- hangs here
    #anything below here doesnt work
    #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    print('given')
    await ctx.send(f'Server now has: **${servercoins}**')
```

any help is appreciated (typing random stuff because my post is mostly code and i need to put these edits but stack overflow is being rude so yeah)

Comment: What is the error, or if there is none, where does it hang? What are `servercoins` and `servermultiplier` set to?

Comment: @EricJin servercoins is set to any integer, servermultiplier is set to 1, and there is no error but it hangs at ```servercoins += 1 * servermultiplier```

Comment: It works for me. Does your first `print` statement work? Can you edit in more code into the question?

Comment: @EricJin done, im so confused

Comment: Can you post the entire bot's code? There is no way that the function itself is the issue.

Comment: @EricJin trust me, it is, every other function works, but i will edit the post to include all of the code

Comment: You set `servercoins` and `servermultiplier` to `result[0]` and `result[1]`. This might cause the issue (but it shouldn't cause it to hang...); you can try converting them to ints first in your `on_ready`.

Comment: @EricJin this worked, thank you, make a answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you set

```py
servermultiplier = 1
servercoins = 0
```

but then modified it into a string in `on_ready`:

```py
    for line in file1:
        count += 1
        result.append( line.strip())
    servercoins = result[0]
    serermultiplier = result[1]  # note that there's a typo here
```

Here, `result` is a list of strings, so `servercoins` is set to a string. (This is why globals are bad!)

You later try to add it `servercoins += 1 * servermultiplier`, which is not allowed.

```py
>>> servercoins = '0'
>>> servermultiplier = 1
>>> servercoins += 1 * servermultiplier
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I still don't know why it causes the code to hang. I would assume that the exception stopped the rest of the command from executing, and then it was silently ignored later on.